# Estoy trabajando con un array quiero extraer esta información

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, javascript-objeto

Estoy trabajando con arrays, al hacer la consulta inserto lo consultado en mi array pero quiero que solo me aparesca el link mas no todas esas lineas, a i c b f h g

[image: firebase.storage().ref(socios/${banner.drive ? banner.banner+"_a" : banner.banner}).getDownloadURL();]

Comment: Eso no es un `array`, es un `object` de `JS`.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección

Comment: no se que codigo usas para armar el array pero una solucion seria por ejemplo usar un condicional link.forach(el => el =! null || el != false ? //almacenar el dato en el array : "";

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
        name : "mamerto",
        socio : "kbsadfbnesanfdns",
        location : "null",
        banner : "iusdhefnsadn",
        orden : 1,
        lastnames : "Wenceslao Barifloja",
        state : "",
        placa : "PQB-0507",
        activity : "true",
        marca : "Topota",
        year : "9999",
        phone : "874365476327876583274",
        num : "01",
        id : "kushbdfnsfnsn",
        link : {
            a : 2,
            i : "lkjdsnfnds",
            c : null,
            b : null,
            f : null,
            h : false,
            g : false
        }
    }

    console.log(obj.link.i);
```

Concatenando los objetos, no hace falta que esté todo dentro de un array.

Pd: Te estás dando cuenta que estás dando los datos de un tal Carlos Saul, con un toyota, con su numero de telefono etc?